# SharePoint online error: Save Conflict. Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user

Tags: sharepoint-online

In a SharePoint online custom edit form, an item is being updated and on change event, a workflow gets triggered.
This workflow takes almost 2 mins to execute. 
Within 2 mins, if anyone again updates the same item, below error occurs on save:

**Save Conflict.
Your changes conflict with those made concurrently by another user. If you want your changes to be applied, click Back in your Web browser, refresh the page, and resubmit your changes.**

It makes sense as same item is being updated by user as as well workflow.
What can be done to overcome this, as both edit and workflow are necessary actions.

Comment: one thing I can think of is to check the workflow status on my form load, if workflow is still in progress then restrict the user from editing else allow. But what would be the most elegant way to achieve this!!! Users must not feel frustrated...

Comment: May be you can show/hide SP.UI wait screen with appropriate message after form is saved, based on  workflow status.

Comment: this is SharePoint behaviour. so either you need to edit form 2 min after completing a workflow. or you can apply workflow functionality using your custom form

Comment: @NegiRox Yes this is what I am doing, allowing user to edit once the WF is completed.

Answer (score 0):

Currently what I am doing is when user comes to edit the same item, I am checking the workflow status.
If WF is still in progress, I am giving below prompt on form load:
[image]

If WF status is completed then I am allowing the user to proceed with the edit form.